# IFTTT maker channel and Security Concerns

Tags: raspberry-pi, automation

This is about IFTTT Maker Channel and security around it. They announced a new Maker Channel recently where you can receive and make web requests for automation. 
For example, I can turn ON/OFF my home lighting by looking it up with Google Home. This works flawlessly by using a raspberry pi and then exposing it with a web request.

I will have to do a port forward with my home router to be able to receive requests from IFTTT. - This is my understanding on how it works.

Now, the question. is - I am exposing a web request from open internet to my home automation. The secret is the web request parameters on http channel. If one knows the URL, he can do everything IFTTT can (manually)...correct?

How can I secure it?

Answer (score 1):

I guess HTTPS and put the secret in the body. Other than that, I don't think you can really secure it more, which is a shame. Also, you would need a certificate for your Raspbery PI.